# How $a_{13}=0$ in $\begin{bmatrix} {2}&{1}&{0}\\ {1}&{3}&{5} \end{bmatrix}$?

Tags: matrices, notation

I'm reading Artin's *Algebra*.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
{2}&{1}&{0}\\ 
{1}&{3}&{5}
\end{bmatrix}$$

It says that $a_{ij}$ is the matrix entry such that **$i$ is the horizontal coordinate and $j$ is the vertical coordinate**. It gives some examples: $a_{11}=2, a_{13}=0,a_{23}=5$. I don't understand why $a_{13}=0$ The first number in the first row is $2$, the first number in the third row does not exist. The only way to make this interpretation valid would be to consider the matrix (it would also work for $a_{23}$):

$$\begin{bmatrix}
{2}&{1}\\ 
{1}&{3}\\
{0}&{5}
\end{bmatrix}$$

It kinda makes sense, is it possible that when such a situation occur, we just *spin* the matrix?

Comment: I would say that $i$ is the vertical coordinate and $j$ is the horizontal one. When you change $i$ you go up or down in the matrix, hence the change is vertical.

Comment: Verbatim, `The index i is called the row index, and j is the column index.` and not what you wrote. Also, given all the examples there I can't really see how could you get such a confusion.

Comment: I think people are missing the point of the question which isn't a misconception of what $a_{13}$ is, but rather an apparent contradiction between the definition of $a_{ij}$ and what the authors want to convey.

Comment: @Ilya [Here](http://i.imgur.com/ATsATFl.jpg).

Comment: @GitGud: the author defines $a_{ij}$ as usual, please see my comment above where I copied the book. 2Vyska: everything is correct there, and yet I don't see the words *horizontal* or *vertical* in the book.

Comment: @Ilya I said 'apparent', it doesn't change my point regarding people (apart from Rory) not answering the actual question.

Comment: Google Book Search finds no instance of "horizontal coordinate" or "vertical coordinate" in Michael Artin's *Algebra* (Prentice Hall, 1991).

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked if it *spins*. I showed the reason why I thought that.

Comment: @GitGud: I didn't disagree on your point regarding not addressing the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It says that $a_{ij}$ is the matrix entry such that **$i$ is the horizontal coordinate and $j$ is the vertical coordinate**

It does not.

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't you deduce it from that figure?

Comment: From that figure I would only deduce that $i$ is the row index, and $j$ it the column one. The horizontal coordinate is where *on a given row* am I situated: that would be $j$.

Answer (score 3):

The definition you gave from your book is ambiguous. Here are some other definitions.

The classic book *A Survey of Modern Algebra* by Birkhoff and MacLane, Third edition, page 159, says:

> whose $i$th row consists of the components $a_{i1}, \ldots, a_{in}$

Some other books just give a standard template for a matrix:

> $$
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
>         a_{21} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
>         \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>         a_{m1} & \cdots & a_{mn} \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $$

Your definition is simply wrong. The first coordinate is the row, the second is the column.

Answer (score 1):

$a_{13}$ is the rightmost column in the first row (above $a_{23} = 5$), which is clearly $0$. In all other texts, $i$ describes the row (vertical) and $j$ the column (horizontal), it seems like your text got that wrong.

Comment: Yes, but I am confronting that information with another information given in the book.

Comment: I edited some stuff above. The interpretation of $a_{ij}$ in all of linear algebra texts is different than what your text says, they most likely got the vertical/horizontal wrong.

Comment: Refer to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Notation
This is the convention in every single meaningful text.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the entries of a matrix as vectors, every row being a vector.

So, $a_{ij}$ is the $j$-th coordinate of the $i$-th vector.

In this case $a_{13}$ is the 3rd coordinate of the 1st vector.